# paginate logs from Google Cloud Logging in Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to the [documentation here](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/usage.html), the correct way to paginate results is:

```
pages = iterator.pages
```

However, that doesn't work.  I get an error saying:

```
 'generator' object has no attribute 'pages'
```

This does work:

```
import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
iterator = client.list_entries(page_size=5)
page1 = next(iterator)
for entry in page1:
    print(entry)
```

However, how do I request the results for a specific page?  The documentation says to use 'nextPageToken' as a parameter to list_entries, but I don't see any pagetoken present in the results to use.

Comment: Define what you mean by specific page. The `nextPageToken` is included for each page if there is another page. It is not used as an index into the following pages.

Answer (score 1):

With Google APIs, when you have a long return, you have pagination. Each server response has a next page token to request to get the following result of this list.

Here, you are looking for going immediately to a defined page number, for example, jump immediately to the lasted page, or to the page 5. And you can't, the APIs aren't designed like this.